# removeChild, textContent and appendChild are deprecated. Alternatives?

Tags: javascript

I ask this question based on the following link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr

I see so many developers use these methods and honestly I am not entirely sure if they are really deprecated as a whole or just in a certain context. Either way, it does list them as deprecated, which is why im asking: what valid and up-to-date alternatives are there? Specifically for:

removeChild, textContent, appendChild. Even insertBefore is deprecated.

Comment: Mozilla is listing the alternatives there only.

Comment: @AkshayArora some alternatives are mentioned but it is not really clear. They could have added more information.

Comment: @Asperger thanks for the heads up... `cloneNode`...`appendChild`...no alternatives mentioned and I can't think of a valid JS replacement at the moment. -_-

Comment: @zer00ne no problem. You might want to check out the answer below. Pretty interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are confusing `node` objects and `attribute` objects. The functions you named are commonly used with the former, but not the latter. The MDN article is *only* describing `attribute` objects.

For more information:

A `<div>` is a node, and it could have an attribute `data-foo="bar"` on it. 
It is common to append children or modify text to a node. For example, given:

```
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = '<p>Hello</p><p> World</p>';
node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
```

would produce HTML of `<div><p> World</p></div>`

However, this doesn't really make sense for attributes. Attributes are essentially just strings attached to a node. The common actions that are used with attributes are `name` and `value`. For example:

```
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.setAttribute('data-foo', 'bar');
var attr = node.getAttributeNode('data-foo');
console.log(attr.name); // prints 'data-foo'
console.log(attr.value); // prints 'bar'
console.log(typeof attr); // prints 'object'
```

At least personally, I have rarely had use for the `Attr` object, instead `node.getAttribute('data-foo')` returns a `string` of `bar`, and that is sufficient for my needs.

As to why those methods exist in the first place on `attr` objects, I will simply copy/paste from the MDN article you linked:

> Warning: In DOM Core 1, 2 and 3, Attr inherited from Node. This is no longer the case in DOM4. In order to bring the implementation of Attr up to specification, work is underway to change it to no longer inherit from Node. You should not be using any Node properties or methods on Attr objects.

Comment: But who on earth does that with attributes? I mean why was such a thing ever possible in the first place? Kind of weird right?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, ARs, that's a relief. I'm with Asp on that one, though-- *who does that?*  and your personal take is mine as well--`getAttribute` is more than adequate. Sometimes I feel MDN is so clinical you need to be lawyer to interpret their descriptions.

Comment: It looks like a mistake in the original DOM specification, which has been subsequently fixed. However, for backwards compatibility, the functions haven't been removed.